# Android remove top block of activity screen

Tags: android, android-activity

I am pretty new to android development and would like to remove the space with appName at the top as shown in the picture (The area where it says BasicCalculator). I want to be able to customize it with different colors and do other stuff there. How is that done?

thanks

[image]

Comment: Try adding `getActionBar().hide();` in the `onCreate()` method of your activity.

Comment: You would want to visit [this site here](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=holo&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&texture=0&hairline=0&backColor=E4E4E4%2C100&secondaryColor=D6D6D6%2C100&tabColor=33B5E5%2C100&tertiaryColor=F2F2F2%2C100&accentColor=33B5E5%2C100&cabBackColor=FFFFFF%2C100&cabHighlightColor=33B5E5%2C100) to customize your app's ActionBar. Choose your own colors, etc. Then download, extract and copy to your app's `res` folder. Then, if you need additional customization's, you can modify the `styles.xml` (_or the equivalent_).

Comment: This is a good read too: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html. Also, if you only need to remove it and not customize it, @vikram is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in your onCreate() method.

```
//Remove title bar
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

//Remove notification bar
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```